# Lastest updates destroyed right click menus in Chromium 100.---

Tags: chromium

Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Only seems to impact Chromium web browser, all other right click menus seem to work normally. I only see a solid block of mixed characters.
I tried updating to the latest Chromium version, 100.0.4878.0 (Official Build) snap (64-bit) but no change.
Anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: This sounds like a bug. Please [report it](https://askubuntu.com/q/5121). If the problem is only with Chromium, maybe you should purge and reinstall it .

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to do that.

Comment: Chromium 100.0.4878.0 is in the latest/edge channel. "Edge" by definition means "unstable". If you don't want to install unstable software, switch to latest/stable channel, where current Chromium version is 98.0.4758.80.

Comment: That's not the problem. This issue started with the latest update. At  that time I was using Chromium 98.0.4758.80. When the problem appeared, I updated to the latest version of Chrome hoping that would fix the issue. It did not.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue went away when I switched from using the built-in Radeon Graphics driver to the proprietary one distributed by AMD.

So I suspect it's a graphics library issue.

My system has integrated Radeon graphics for a AMD Ryzen 3 2200G processor.

1. Downloaded from here:
   http://repo.radeon.com/amdgpu-install/latest/ubuntu/focal/
2. Executed the downloaded .deb file.
3. Installed via:
   $ amdgpu-install -y --usecase=graphics

as per:
https://amdgpu-install.readthedocs.io/en/21.40/install-installing.html?highlight=ubuntu#installing-the-all-open-use-case